# Targetting JCE editor

Tags: jce

When I have tiny MCE as the default editor I was able to add html to the editor using this javascript command

```
var content = tinyMCE.get(editor).getContent();
content = tinyMCE.get(editor).setContent("");
jInsertEditorText(html, editor);
```

What do I need to do to target both editors or all editors please?

Mat

Comment: Do you need to do this in JS without access to PHP?

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience **tinymce** variable. has the access to any editor, and you can access the content with **tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()**.

NOTE: There is only one special case with Zoo, where the previous sentence returns empty, and you have to call *tinymce.editors[0].getContent()* instead.